# Editing styles in a sepertate resource file using blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

So, I have a style in a file called Styles.xaml right, then in my XAML view I have a link to in in my resource dictionary, this all works fine.

Now, in Expression Blend 4 I have a list box, and when I click "ListBox" -> "Edit Additional Templates" -> "Edit Generated Item Container {ItemsContainerStyle}" but Edit Current is greyed out - I don't want to edit a copy of the style, that's the whole reason I have just one for the whole app in my Styles.xaml file. Does anyone know why this is? and if it can be changed?

Off course I would just open the styls.xaml file and edit it there but as we all know we can't do that :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If EditCurrent is greyed out it means that ItemsContainerStyle on the ListBox is not set to a valid style.

BTW: You can edit resources directly in any resource dictionary, in your case simply open styls.xaml in Blend, you'll see a message stating it can't be edited in design view.

Now go to the Resources tab and expad the node containing styles.xaml and you'll see a full list of resources contained in the file. Now click on the edit resource button to the right of the resource you would like to edit.

Comment: Oh sweet - I will have to check that out... I didn't know that.

Comment: Regarding your first point though, I know the style is set, I can see it - run it - and if I change it in the styles.xaml manually I am all set, I can even say "edit a copy" at which point it copies it (even blank lines) in the window.resources (or usercontrol whatever...). But again, if I can get to the styles the way you suggested than I am all set! Thanks!